# Prove that if g is injective, f is injective

Tags: proof-writing

$f \colon A \to \mathbb R$ be a function (where $A$ is some set) and define the function
$g \colon A \to \mathbb R$ as
$g(x) = 3 (f(x))^2 + 1.$
Prove if $g$ is injective then $f$ is injective

How do I prove the composite of the function is injective? I know for injection every $x$ value equals a y value $(x = y)$ for injection. Is this correct:

$3(f(y))^2 + 1= 3(f(x))^2 + 1 = f(y) = f(x)$

Comment: Remember what injective means. Whenever $g(y) = g(x)$ then $x = y$.

Comment: It isn't always true.  Suppose $f(x) = x$ on $\mathbb{R}$, which is clearly injective (one-one).  However $x^2 = (-x)^2$, so for your given $g(x)$ the composition is *not* injective.  A general proposition is that the composition of injective functions is still injective, but your quadratic real polynomial $g(x)$ is not injective.

Comment: This is no right $3(f(y))^2 + 1= 3(f(x))^2 + 1 = f(y) = f(x)$. Since $f(x)\not = g(x)$

Comment: You *don't* prove the composition of the functions is injective - that is a condition of the problem that you are supposed to assume is true.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $g(x)$ is inyective. Then if you have $g(x)=g(y)$ then $x=y$. What does it mean on $f(x)$.

Suposse

$$f(x)=f(y) $$

then

$$g(x)=3f(x)^3+1=3f(y)^3+1=g(y)$$

which implies

$$x=y$$

Since $g$ is inyective.

in general if you have that $g=h\circ f$ is inyective then $f$ is inyective.

Answer (score 0):

Since g is injective, we have
$$\forall x,y \in A \,\,\, if  \,\,\ g(x)=g(y) \to x=y  \,\,\,\, (1)$$
Now assume $f(x)=f(y)$, we want to prove, in this case also $x$ equals to $y$. We have,
$$f(x)=f(y) \to (f(x))^2=(f(y))^2 \to 3(f(x))^2=3(f(y))^2 \\ 
\to 3(f(x))^2+1=3(f(y))^2+1 \to g(x)=g(y)$$
Therefore, using equation (1), we conclude $x=y$, so
$$f(x)=f(y) \to x=y$$
and therefore f is injective.